# AEM: How to fetch not of node name 'XX' using query builder?

Tags: java, aem, query-builder

It seems query builder operations can only work on properties but not on node names.

I am trying to achieve the following,

```
path=/content/abc/
type=cq:Page
nodename.nodename=XX
nodename.operation=unequals
```

, where I do not want to fetch nodes with name `XX`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AEM: How to find the nodes with property name "customProp" and empty property value, using query builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140247/aem-how-to-find-the-nodes-with-property-name-customprop-and-empty-property-va)

Comment: The two questions are separate, as other one talks about property and this one about nodename (part of of jcr path). I edited the question to make it clear. Please let me know, if it does not communicate the difference between the two questions.

Comment: The first thing you'll want to look at is the docs for the OOTB predicates. As of now, you're trying to apply functionality of the `JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator` to the `NodenamePredicateEvaluator` which doesn't support `operation`. https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/AbstractPredicateEvaluator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up handling it, by iterating through result set and removing the result with node name XX.