# AEM: How to find the nodes with property name "customProp" and empty property value, using query builder?

Tags: aem, query-builder

There are nodes which have properties but no values.

I am trying to avoid those nodes in query builder using,

```
path=/content/
type=cq:Page
2_property=jcr:content/customProp
2_property.operation=exists
3_property=jcr:content/customProp
3_property.operation=unequals
3_property.value=
```

But the empty value condition (3_property) is being ignored.
How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue to search for all occurrence of a propertiy with no value.
I constructed the following SQL2 Query:

```
SELECT * FROM [{{jcr:primaryType}}] AS ref WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([{{Start Path}}]) AND ref.[{{Property Name}}] = ''
```

In your case I think something like should work

```
SELECT * FROM [{{jcr:primaryType}}] AS ref WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([{{Start Path}}]) AND NOT(ref.[{{Property Name}}] = '')
```